# Picture of a camel's red blood cells

Tags: cell-biology, zoology, microbiology, mammals, red-blood-cell

I'm an art student in need of a little help. I'm looking for microscopic pictures of camel's red blood cells, I need their shape for an art project.

The pictures I find on Google seem a little sketchy as in *"is it reeeeeally camel blood or is it from some other animal?"* kind of sketchy.

I have tried looking further on the net and in books, but without any luck so far. I hope there is someone out there who can help, thanks for reading anyway!

Comment: Do you expect a camel red blood cell to have a drastically different shape than the red blood cells of other mammals? Why don't you just consider any picture of red blood cell?

Comment: @Remi.b They do indeed (as other Camelidae as well).

Comment: Instead of using the answer section for comments, please do this in the comments. You can always comment on your own questions. If the answers suits you, it would also be nice if you would accept it. This brings some extra reputation to the person who wrote it and is a thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unlike humans and most of mammals, which have a biconcave (or "doughnut shaped") RBC, camels have oval shaped (or elliptical) erythrocytes.

The very first result in Google shows this:

[image: Camel erythrocytes compared to human]

That feature (which [protects them from dehydration](https://asknature.org/strategy/blood-cells-protect-from-dehydration/#.WeVEeFuCxdg)) is not unique to camels, but occurs in other Camelidae as well. This is an image of Llama blood:

[image: Llama erythrocytes]

Those are reliable sources of images (optical microscopy) of real cells.

However, for your project, I believe a scanning electron micrograph can better show the shape.

This is an SEM of elliptical camel (a) and alpaca, another Camelidae (b and c), erythrocytes:

[image: Camelidae erythrocytes]

For comparison, this is the biconcave human erythrocyte:

[image: Human erythrocytes]

**PS**: There is this misinformation that camels' erythrocytes are nucleate. You can read this in several web pages. I have no idea who made this up, or why people keep sharing this wrong information: camels, like any mammal, have **anucleate** erythrocytes. See the post [Do camels have nucleated RBCs or enucleated RBCs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45161/do-camels-have-nucleated-rbcs-or-enucleated-rbcs) for more information.

**EDIT**: The way your question is worded it really seems that you're just asking about the reliability of those sources. However, according to [your comment below](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66898/picture-of-a-camels-red-blood-cells#comment121044_66899), it seems that you are indeed looking for better images. It's hard finding better ones than those indexed by Google, but since your goal is modelling those cells, here are two papers (about a protozoan parasite of camelids) which has some SEM that may suit you. The images are not high-resolution, but the cells are shown in several angles:

- https://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/babesia-cameli-as-a-new-species-infecting-camels-camelus-dromedariusat-assiut-locality-2155-6156-1000700.php?aid=79911
- https://www.ecronicon.com/ecmi/microbiology-ECMI-02-000040.php

In both papers the SEMs are at the bottom (just skip the optical ones, they are not good).

Comment: Wow I did not expect that! +1 Do you know why an ovale shape reduces water loss? They all "swim" in plasma anyway, it is unintuitive to me that the shape would matter at all. Do you know if the hemoglobin is the same? Would be great to come up with a reference for the claim that `camels [..] have anucleate erythrocytes` so that we know who to believe.

Comment: I believe hemoglobin is the same, 2*alpha + 2*beta. I'll check this anyway. The elliptical shape doesn't reduce the water loss, but makes the cells better suited for a "thicker" blood (when the blood as a whole looses water).

Comment: Ah it all makes sense. We actually already had a post on Biology.SE about the question of whether camels have nucleated RBC. I edited your answer to add it.

Comment: Yes this is really interesting.

Comment: @canadianer thanks for editing my broken English, I really appreciate that. I just changed the family (Camelidae) back to normal font, we cannot italicise taxa other than species and genus.

Comment: Ah, now I’ve learned two new things ;)

Comment: @canadianer you're welcome! For bacteria, you can italicise family and below: https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/page/scientific-nomenclature. However, I don't follow that system. To avoid confusion, I used to say to the students: "**never** italicise family, order, class, phylum, kingdom or domain, and **always** italicise genus and species". Also, I'm old school: both the ranks and the taxa should be capitalised. That's why I like to write Family Hominidae, not family hominidae.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answers! I really appreciate that. I was hoping through my question, that I could get a hold on better pictures of the ovale shaped blood cells, than the ones Google have. I'm sorry that I didn't make that clear in the above question. I like the aesthetics of the "pink" ones, do you know where I can find something like those, but in a higher resolution? I may be asking for too much, sorry about that (-:

Comment: @HelleP. please check the edit.

Comment: Nice answer! It's not relevant to the question, but in case anyone's interested I thought I'd point out that camelids also have weird antibodies (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-chain_antibody).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you so much ones again! You have been a great help (-: